# External links read from XML file in Flsah

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I was wondering how you use Actionscript 2, to read a URL/web address in a XML file and when you click a button, or an icon, you are then taken to a page specified in the XML document?

Hope you can help, and if you need more details don't hesitate to ask.

Snakespan

Answer (score 0):

I add another answer based on your code.

function released()
{
    gotoURL(this.link, "_blank");
}

I think you should call the 'url' property 'link' as the url is reserved by AS. Just in case.

Hope this is it,
Rob

/////////////////////

Hi,

Here is a quick example for loading and parsing links from an external xml file:

XML file (saved as links.xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <links>
        <link><![CDATA[http://heartcode.robertpataki.com]]></link>
        <link><![CDATA[http://www.adobe.com]]></link>
        <link><![CDATA[http://www.youtube.com]]></link>
    </links>
```

AS (I put the script on the first frame in a new fla document and saved it as links.fla):

```
var xml:XML = new XML();
xml.ignoreWhite = true;
xml.onLoad = parseXML;
xml.load("links.xml");

var extLinks:Array = new Array();

function parseXML(success:Boolean):Void
{
    if(success)
    {
        var i:Number = 0;
        var l:Number = xml.firstChild.childNodes.length;
        while(i<l)
        {
            extLinks[i] = xml.firstChild.childNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
            ++i;
        }

        trace(extLinks);
    }
    else
    {
        trace("Could not load the xml file.");
    }
};
```

When you publish the Flash document you will see it traces the links that are loaded from the XML file.

I hope this is what you seek for,
Rob

Comment: One more thing. Here is some more info about the XML parsing in AS2: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/xml/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, please see the code I've posted above for more details.

Comment: In AS2 does extLinks[i] work for adding, or do you need extLinks.push()?

Answer (score 0):

Your method could be right, but my XML and Flash is a little different to the example you gave, as I have individual icons on a carousel, and I want each one to have a different external link, so my XML is something like:

```
<icons>
<icon image="icon1.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Assets" url="www.mysite.com" /></icon>
</icon>
```

and my Flash is something like:

```
xml.onLoad = function()
{
    var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;
    numOfItems = nodes.length;
    for(var i=0;i<numOfItems;i++)
    {
        var t = home.attachMovie("item","item"+i,i+1);
        t.angle = i * ((Math.PI*2)/numOfItems);
        t.onEnterFrame = mover;
        t.toolText = nodes[i].attributes.tooltip;
        t.url = nodes[i].attributes.url;
        t.icon.inner.loadMovie(nodes[i].attributes.image);
        t.r.inner.loadMovie(nodes[i].attributes.image);
        t.icon.onRollOver = over;
        t.icon.onRollOut = out;
        t.icon.onRelease = released;
    }
}
```

but of course this could be wrong, as I don't set up my function as a success/failure Boolean. Is there a way I could modify this method (or yours) so that I could get a handle on the individual icon and then when I click, it takes me to a site?

Hope you can help,

Snakespan.